# Why not do the hotfixes directly in release instead of branching from master?

Tags: git, release-management, git-flow

Following the git-flow model, I am supposed to delete the `release` branch after merging it into `master` and `develop` and do the hotfixes in their own branches. I was wondering why that is ?

What's wrong with keeping the `release` branch after the merge with `master` (and `develop`) and just do the fixes in the `release` and merge with master (and `develop`) whenever a fix has to be made in the live system?

Answer (score 0):

Hotfixes are meant to be quick fixes to bugs that need immediate attention and cannot wait until the next release to be implemented; therefore, the code being pushed is more of an emergency fix than anything else. That is why the flow is create a new branch, make the needed changes, push back to master.

What this does is prevent any changes that you are working on in release or another branch from sneaking its way into master early, without the proper review cycle.

It is described pretty well here https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow under "Maintenance Branches":

> Having a dedicated line of development for bug fixes lets your team
>   address issues without interrupting the rest of the workflow or
>   waiting for the next release cycle. You can think of maintenance
>   branches as ad hoc release branches that work directly with master.

Also, when merging the release branch into the master branch you are signifying that everything in the branch is done and it has gone through the proper review flow. In that sense, there is nothing left to do in that branch and you can delete it. When you merge it into the master branch, the code, in a sense, no longer belongs to the release branch, but rather the master branch which it has been merged with.